# How does parse server generate id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have an old codebase where parse-server is used with MongoDB. And it generate _id as a string instead of ObjectId. I want to replace parse-server to mongoose. Is it possible to generate string ids with mongoose? Currently I don't want to change existing ids. What you can suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the oldest function known to mankind in programming world `.toString()` can do the job for you, with `mongoose > 5.4.0` you can convert any `ObjectID` to `string` using `.toString()`.

You can read about it [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-54-global-schematype-configuration.html#schematype-getters)

Comment: The same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874830/using-mongo-bson-objectid-with-parse-server

Comment: Ohh I had no idea that `parse-server` generates it's own ID, I thought you are getting `ObjectId` and you want to convert it to `string`

Comment: Can I generate string _id, when I save document?

Comment: If using MongoDB directly, yes. Through Parse Server it is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from Parse-server code (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/2b26cc043e6a06f9c61ea17227a3f88e69310d14/src/cryptoUtils.js#L16)

````
//
// Note: to simplify implementation, the result has slight modulo bias,
// because chars length of 62 doesn't divide the number of all bytes
// (256) evenly. Such bias is acceptable for most cases when the output
// length is long enough and doesn't need to be uniform.
export function randomString(size: number): string {
  if (size === 0) {
    throw new Error('Zero-length randomString is useless.');
  }
  const chars =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + '0123456789';
  let objectId = '';
  const bytes = randomBytes(size);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
    objectId += chars[bytes.readUInt8(i) % chars.length];
  }
  return objectId;
}

// Returns a new random alphanumeric string suitable for object ID.
export function newObjectId(size: number = 10): string {
  return randomString(size);
} ```
````

Comment: please, expand your answer to explain exactly how this code snippet could help with the issue at hand.